# ADB Commands and flags - Definitive Windows documentation?

Tags: android, command-line, adb

Is there a detailed and definitive list of valid commands, flags etc somewhere?

I'm running it via a **Windows7** command prompt and trying to do some simple stuff (like filter a list of files without going in to shell, listing files by date-time etc).

The official documentation is very sparse and I'm assuming that this is because the **ADB** stuff comes from Unix commands and we're supposed to figure it out from there.

I've found some Unix documentation on ls command and tried -c flag but it is unknown.

Other searches have turned up people using **adb ls -la** and this does work, but it's not mentioned in either the official documentation OR Unix ls flags.

Comment: Try to avoid asking question in a single paragraph.It will reduce the question quality & hence your question will not get more 'Views' & high quality answers.Keep in mind such things while you asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://codeadapter.blogspot.in/) is my blog .I have collected some of the major ADB commands from various sites & books. I think it will be useful for you. Let me know in case of any doubts.

**UPDATE**

There is no need of official document .Because `'ls'` is actually a **linux command** & it's usage is officially listed in some linux journals.

'`adb ls`' is actually executing the inside the shell of Android kernal through **Android Debug Bridge** with the help of (adbd)

There is some **ADB (Android) specific commands** like `adb push` & Its documentation is available.

Comment: Thanks Don, some useful info there that I'll definitely refer to but I'm still on the lookout for definitive/official list. I'm still shocked that for something as simple as "adb ls" there is no documentation as to what valid flags can be used.

Comment: Nice update. That's what I was trying to say, I have no knowledge of linux commands, found a site listing some (such as the -c in question), tried them only to find that they're not recognised.

Comment: Unfortunately my original query hasn't been answered so I'll have to leave it open

Comment: Just revisiting this. Since there doesn't appear to be any definitive list or official docs this is accpeted answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "definitive list of valid commands" for `adb shell`. It is just a communication tool you use to access the Android device's shell from your PC. It's like expecting 
[Windows RDP Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) to provide help for all programs you could possibly install on your Windows system.

Also StackOverflow works much better for questions like "please help me with this specific problem" than for questions like "tell me all the different things I can do".

Here are some links to get you started:

- [mksh (default Android shell) manual](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/sh.htm)
- [busybox (popular 3rd-party tool) manual](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html)
- [toolbox (standard Android tool similar to busybox)](http://elinux.org/Android_toolbox)
- [toolbox source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/master/toolbox/)

Here is how to use the source code to find the list of "flags" supported by a specific command, let's say `ls`:

1. you open the source code file for the specific command, i.e. [toolbox/ls.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/toolbox/ls.c)
2. find the part where command line arguments are being processed
3. write them down

   ```
               case 'l': flags |= LIST_LONG; break;
               case 'n': flags |= LIST_LONG | LIST_LONG_NUMERIC; break;
               case 's': flags |= LIST_SIZE; break;
               case 'R': flags |= LIST_RECURSIVE; break;
               case 'd': flags |= LIST_DIRECTORIES; break;
               case 'Z': flags |= LIST_MACLABEL; break;
               case 'a': flags |= LIST_ALL; break;
               case 'F': flags |= LIST_CLASSIFY; break;
               case 'i': flags |= LIST_INODE; break;
   ```